# Pandas adding rows to df in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm parsing data in a loop and once it's parsed and structured I would like to then add it to a data frame.

The end format of the data frame I would like is something like the following:

```
df:

id   2018-01 2018-02 2018-03  
234     2       1       3
345     4       5       1
534     5       3       4
234     2       2       3
```

When I iterate through the data in the loop I have a dictionary with the id, the month and the value for the month, for example:

```
{'id':234,'2018-01':2}
{'id':534,'2018-01':5}
{'id':534,'2018-03':4}
           .
           .
           .
```

What is the best way to take an empty data frame and add rows and columns with their values to it in a loop?

Essentially as I iterate it would look something like this

```
df:

id   2018-01   
234     2
```

then

```
df:

id   2018-01   
234     2  
534     5
```

then

```
df:

id   2018-01   2018-03
234     2  
534     5         4
```

and so on...

Comment: what is the input data ?>

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to convert the single dict to dataframe firstly, then we do `append`, in case we do not have duplicate `'id'` we need `groupby` get the `first` value

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
l=[{'id':234,'2018-01':2},
{'id':534,'2018-01':5},
{'id':534,'2018-03':4}]

for x in l:
    df=df.append(pd.Series(x).to_frame().T.set_index('id')).groupby(level=0).first()
    print(df)

     2018-01
id          
234        2
     2018-01
id          
234        2
534        5
     2018-01  2018-03
id                   
234      2.0      NaN
534      5.0      4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to generate a new data frame at each iteration and append it, this is quite expensive. If your data is not too big and fits into memory, you can make a list of dictionaries first and then pandas allows you to simply do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(your_list_of_dicts)
df.set_index('id')
```

If making a list is to expensive (because you'd like to save memory for the data frame) consider using a *generator* instead of a list. The basic anatomy of a generator function is this:

```
def datagen(your_input):
    for item in your_input:
        # your code to make a dict
        yield dict
```

The generator object `data = datagen(input)` will not store the dicts but yields a dict at each iteration. It can generate items on demand. When you do `pd.DataFrame(data)`, pandas will stream all the data and make a data frame. Generators can be used for data pipelines (like pipes in UNIX) and are very powerful for big data workflows. Be aware, however, that a generator object can be consumed only once, that is if you run pd.DataFrame(data) again, you will get an empty data frame.

Comment: Can you give more info on why it's adding data to an existing DF in a loop is "expensive"?  As you mentioned, for *memory* the in-place adding of rows would be more memory-efficient; it would be useful to know how time-efficient.  I understand that time per iteration could be a concern for millions of rows, but perhaps for 1000's it is a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found in Pandas (although not intuitive) to iteratively append new data rows to a dataframe is using `df.loc[ ]` to reference the last (nonexistent) row, with `len(df)` as the index:

```
df.loc[ len(df) ] = [new, row, of, data]
```

This will "append" the new data row to the end of the dataframe in-place.

The above example is for an empty Dataframe with exactly 4 columns, such as:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(  columns=["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]  )
```

`df.loc[ ]` indexing can insert data at any Row at all, whether or not it exists yet.  It seems it will never give an `IndexError`, like an *numpy.array* or *List* would if you tried to assign to a nonexistent row.
For a brand-new, empty DataFrame, `len(df)` returns `0`, and thus references the first, blank row, and then increases by one each time you add a row.

–––––

I do not know the speed/memory efficiency cost of this method, but it works great for my modest datasets (few thousand rows).  At least from a memory perspective, I imagine that a large loop appending data to to the target DataFrame directly would use less memory than generating an intermediate List of duplicate data first, then generating a DataFrame from that list.  Time "efficiency" could be a different question entirely, one for the other SO gurus to comment on.

–––––

However for the OP's specific case where you *also* requested to combine the `columns` if the data is for an existing identically-named column, you'd need som logic during your `for` loop.

Instead I would make the DataFrame "dumb" and just import the data as-is, repeating dates as they come, eg. your post-loop DataFrame would look like this, with simple column names describing the *raw* data:

```
df:

id   date      data
234  2018-01   2
534  2018-01   5
535  2018-03   4
```

(has two entries for the same date).

Then I would use the DataFrame's databasing functions to organize this data how you like, probably using some combination of `df.unique()` and `df.sort()`. Will look into that more later.

Comment: BTW, significant confusion appears to come from the fact that the `DataFrame.append()` function operates differently from `List.append()` - List's will `append()` in-place, which DataFrames `append()` returns a new array.  Probably both have the same "cost", requiring the allocation of a whole new array's worth of memory, but `pandas` makes this obvious while `List` hides this from the user.